# most visited document in document library

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

How to get most visited document in document library ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should try Item Level Auditing feature which is implemented by Microsoft.  OR else you can use SPAudit class.

Here is the link:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397403%28v=office.12%29.aspx